# Why the email attachments are not displaying as icons in IOS7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Hi in one of my application I cannot able to see the email attachments as icons. It is showing like inline messages for the mail. Can you please help me to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 and above mail application, the attachment always shows inline.